# Publish an unpublished app from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have seen that there is an option for unpublish my app

[image]

I am interested in unpublish it only for a few weeks. Will I be able to publish it again in the future?

Comment: Your app will loose some ratings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can publish your unpublished app again from Google Play Consol but you have to keep these steps in your mind.

**1. Sign in to Google Play Console:**
Log in to the Google Play Console using the account associated with your app.

**2. Select Your App:**
Navigate to the "All apps" section and select the app you want to republish.

**3. Review Policy Status:**
Check for any policy violations or issues in the "Policy status" section. Resolve any outstanding issues.

**4.Update Content and Resources:**
If necessary, update your app's content, resources, or features to comply with Google Play policies.

**5.Submit for Review:**
Go to the "Release" section and create a new release for your app. Submit it for review.

**6.Wait for Approval:**
Google Play will review your app. Once approved, your app will be published on the Google Play Store.

Hope! this will help you.